# Emacs: how to specify where the true-type font is?

Tags: emacs, fonts

I want to make use of DejaVu font in emacs, on a cluster -- and I don't have access to install fonts system wide. I put fonts (they are free) in `~/.fonts`. I want to make use of `DejaVuSansMono.ttf`. Normally I just put in .emacs:

```
(custom-set-variables 
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :background "#ffffb1" :foreground "#141312" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 173 :width normal :foundry "monotype" :family "DejaVu Sans Mono")))))
```

But now emacs can't find the font!

So my question is - how can I help emacs to find the font? How can I specify the path to the font?

Comment: can your window system find the font?

Comment: @jtahlborn: I'm sorry - but how can I check that?

Comment: can you open up other windowed applications in the system and use that font.  if not, then the font probably isn't installed correctly.

Comment: I've started a firefox at the server - and there in preferences - I can see that firefox aware of dejavu fonts. But I don't know - wither they are mine - or system wide. Actually I don't think that placing fonts in a `~/.fonts` folder alone is equal to an installation. But I think that it is possible to provide emacs a way to search for true type fonts.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `bdf-directory-list` will fix it.

```
(setq bdf-directory-list '("/path/to/fonts"))
```

I can't try it right now - will be back later.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Centos 7 with Emacs 28.2.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with TTF fonts as far as I can tell.